# Querying github project cards with graphql

Tags: github, graphql, querying

I have a Project in Github with some columns, and I'm trying to locate cards (Issues) that are in the closed state.

With GraphQL I'm having trouble constructing a query that can filter the cards.  Currently I have this query:

```
query {
  organization(login:"org") {
    project(number:3) {
      columns(first:1){
        nodes{
          id,
          name,
          cards(first:1){
            nodes{
              content {
                ... on Issue {
                  url,
                  state
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This returns the result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "organization": {
      "project": {
        "columns": {
          "nodes": [
            {
              "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
              "name": "On Deck",
              "cards": {
                "nodes": [
                  {
                    "content": {
                      "url": "https://github.com/org/repo/issues/606",
                      "state": "OPEN"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I have gathered thus far is that the "Project Cards" are "UNION" objects in GraphQL and I have no idea how to add filters to these unions.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm looking to do the same thing and played around but couldn't find anything.  It would seem that you should be able to do a filter like this...

Answer (score 0):

I asked [the same question on the GitHub Community forum](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-API-Development-and/How-to-query-GraphQL-for-all-Issues-in-a-column-with-state/td-p/33464). An admin wrote back:

> The way that the GraphQL API is currently built, no, you can't filter project cards on the state of the issue that they're representing using only the query language. You would have to query all cards in the column and then filter it yourself.

Comment: Doesn't that defeat one of the main strengths of GraphQL; to be able to do much of the processing server-side?